# Как прицепить всплывашку по клику?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

Динамически с помощью Ajax создать таблицу у меня вышло, но необходимо что при клике по ID появлялась всплывашка с детальной информацией

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(function() {
  var output = $('table tbody');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://cm.mmi.macc.com.ua/tests/sample.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var rows = '';
      $.each(data, function(i, el) {
        rows += `<tr>
                      <td>` + el.id + `</td>
                      <td>` + el.name + `</td>
                      <td>` + el.author + `</td>
                      <td>` + el.date + `</td>
                      <td>` + el.number + `</td>
                      <tr>
                `;
      });
      output.html(rows);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
h2 {
  text-align: left;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
}
th {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
hr {
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
      <h2>Demo Application Title</h2>
      <hr>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Название</th>
          <th>Автор</th>
          <th>Дата выпуска</th>
          <th>Серийный номер</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как это реализовать? Пробовал вот так, к примеру:

```
output.on('click', 'tr td:first-child', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

но консоль ругается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var output = $('table tbody'),
    layer = $('#layer'),
    modal = $('#modal');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://cm.mmi.macc.com.ua/tests/sample.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var rows = '';
      $.each(data, function(i, el) {
        rows += `<tr>
        <td data-descr="` + el.description + `" data-img="` + el.img + `">` + el.id + `</td>
        <td>` + el.name + `</td>
        <td>` + el.author + `</td>
        <td>` + el.date + `</td>
        <td>` + el.number + `</td>
        <tr>`;
      });
      output.html(rows);
    }
  });
  output.on('click', 'tr td:first-child', function() {
    var $that = $(this),
      tds = $that.siblings('td'),
      html = '<span class="close">X</span>';
      html += '<h1>' + tds.eq(0).text() + '</h1>';
      html += '<img src="' + $that.data('img') + '" alt="">';
      html += `<ul>
        <li>` + tds.eq(1).text() + `</li>
        <li>` + tds.eq(2).text() + `</li>
        <li>` + tds.eq(3).text() + `</li>
        <li>` + tds.eq(4).text() + `</li>
      </ul>`;
    html += '<div>' + $that.data('descr') + '</div>';
    modal.html(html);
    layer.fadeIn();
  });
  layer.on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
      $(this).fadeOut();
    }
  });
  modal.on('click', '.close', function(e) {
    layer.trigger('click');
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
th {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
tr td:first-child {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#layer {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: auto;
}
#layer::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: -.36em;
}
#modal {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#modal img {
  max-height: 200px;
}
#modal ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
#modal ul li:not(:first-child) {
  border-left: 1px solid #999;
}
#modal .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Название</th>
    <th>Автор</th>
    <th>Дата выпуска</th>
    <th>Серийный номер</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<div id="layer">
  <div id="modal"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @zorro дополнил код кнопкой для закрытия окна

Comment: ок спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1):

Вроде, все работает...

```js
$(function() {
  var output = $('table tbody');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://cm.mmi.macc.com.ua/tests/sample.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var rows = '';
      $.each(data, function(i, el) {
        rows += `<tr>
                      <td>` + el.id + `</td>
                      <td>` + el.name + `</td>
                      <td>` + el.author + `</td>
                      <td>` + el.date + `</td>
                      <td>` + el.number + `</td>
                      <tr>
                `;
      });
      output.html(rows);
    }
  });
});
$('table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

```css
h2 {
  text-align: left;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
}
th {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
hr {
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
      <h2>Demo Application Title</h2>
      <hr>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Название</th>
          <th>Автор</th>
          <th>Дата выпуска</th>
          <th>Серийный номер</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @zorro, какая-то прям загадка. Я вам уже вчера [дал ответ и ответ полный](http://codepen.io/lazyden/pen/jAdmdZ?editors=1010), со всеми вашими "всплывашками" и другими рюшками. Зачем вы удаляли тему (*не будем уточнять где*) - мне абсолютно не ясно.

Comment: Денис я не удалял, мне пришло сообщение с информацией что данный вопрос удален администратором.

Comment: дайте ответ здесь и я его отмечу правильным. Спасибо.